# Excel: string split

Tags: excel

Can anyone tell me the formula to split the a8399em,a1445f01m,h60853w....from the strings

I have this kind of strings:

```
.../images/options/kiss-off-t-shirt_red_men_tshirts_a8399em.jpg

.../images/options/ask-me-if-i-care--t-shirt_black_men_tshirts_a1445f01m.jpg

.../images/options/thumbs/dont-marry-by-happy-women-t-shirt_blue_women_tshirts_thumb_h60853w.jpg
```

I need to split this a8399em from the string

As you can see before the number that i need, there is a "_" and after the number there is a "."

Thanks

Comment: like if there were not enough resources on SO or online in general that teach you how split string in Excel...

Answer (score 1):

With your string in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"*",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"*",""))))+1,255),".jpg","")  and copy down